# Trouble With VBA VLookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am having trouble with the below VLookup since I am using a the full column range as my lookup value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim WsFk_Row As Long
Dim WsFk_Clm As Long

Table1 = Sheets("Requirements Update Format").Range("A:A")
Table2 = Sheets("Workstreams Link").Range("A:B")
Set WsFk_Row = Sheets("Requirements Insert Format").Range("I1").Row
Set WsFk_Clm = Sheets("Requirements Insert Format").Range("I1").Column


For Each cl In Table1
    Sheets("Requirements Insert Format").Cells(WsFk_Row, WsFk_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 2, False)
    WsFk_Row = WsFk_Row + 1
Next cl

End Sub
```

This code appropriately populates all rows, however once completed I receive the following error "Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class". This led me to believe the following line is where my issue begins

```
Table1 = Sheets("Requirements Update Format").Range("A:A")
```

I tried resolving this by modifying the line as below, however this prevented the process to run at all.

```
Table1 = Sheets("Requirements Update Format").Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select)
```

Any suggestion on how I can resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you need a `Set` in front of Table1 and Table2? and I don't think you want `set` for your next two lines.

Comment: I'd say it's because it didn't find the lookup value: did it actually populate ALL cells?

Comment: @user3598756 I believe you are correct and the reason is the loop goes one beyond the last populated cell in Table1. What I am hoping to achieve is to avoid this error from occurring by limiting Table1 to include only cells with a value in column A. This would have to be dynamic as the number of rows in that column will change frequently.

Comment: See posted answer (sorry I can't test nor format it properly) which also takes Into account Forward Ed's comment

Comment: @user3598756 got you covered, I edited your answer and added formatting to the code for you so it will read better.  Just need to wait for edits to be approved now.

Comment: @Forward Ed thank you. But I was making an edit myself (adding newlines to try and improve a little) so I'm not sure your edits weren’t rejected. BTW how to access test formatting buttons from a smartphone?

Comment: @user3598756 Give me a smart phone and I'll try and figure it out 8)...is there a way to by pass the mobile version of the site (if there is one) and go to the full version of the site in your web browser?  I am wondering if those formatting buttons at the top of the answer area are removed on a different version of this page.  YOU EDIT CODE ON YOUR SMARTPHONE ....You finger poking animal!

Comment: @Forward Ed: I agree... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were on the right track. Try the following ...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim WsFk_Row As Long, WsFk_Clm As Long
Dim Sht1 As Worksheet, Sht2 As Worksheet, Sht3 As Worksheet
Dim Table1 As Range, Table2 As Range
Dim cl As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

Set Sht1 = Worksheets("Requirements Update Format")
Set Sht2 = Worksheets("Workstreams Link")
Set Sht3 = Worksheets("Requirements Insert Format")

lastRow = Sht1.Range("A" & Sht1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Table1 = Sheets("Requirements Update Format").Range("A1:A" & lastRow)

lastRow = Sht2.Range("A" & Sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Table2 = Sheets("Workstreams Link").Range("A1:B" & lastRow)

WsFk_Row = Sht3.Range("I1").Row
WsFk_Clm = Sht3.Range("I1").Column

For Each cl In Table1
    Sht3.Cells(WsFk_Row, WsFk_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 2, False)
    WsFk_Row = WsFk_Row + 1
Next cl

Set Sht1 = Nothing
Set Sht2 = Nothing
Set Sht3 = Nothing
Set Table1 = Nothing
Set Table2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

It does this:

- Uses a couple of more objects, hopefully to improve readability
- Corrects some syntax around `Set`
- Calculates the actual size of the tables. This prevents the cl loop from shooting past the end of the usable range.
- Cleans up the objects at the end - just good practice

Answer (score 2):

Edited to substitute "VlookUp" with ".Find" method and handle possible not matchings

```
Dim WsFk_Row As Long, WsFk_Clm As Long
Dim found as Range
With Sheets("Requirements Update Format")

    Set Table1 = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End (xlUp).Row)

End With

Set Table2 = Sheets("Workstreams Link").Range("A:B")

WsFk_Row = Sheets("Requirements Insert Format").Range("I1").Row

WsFk_Clm = Sheets("Requirements Insert Format").Range("I1").Column


For Each cl In Table1
   Set found = Table2. Columns(1).Find (What:=cl.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole,  LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase=True)
   If Not found is Nothing then Sht3.Cells(WsFk_Row, WsFk_Clm) =  found.Offset (,1)
   WsFk_Row = WsFk_Row + 1
Next cl

End Sub
```

Comment: For future reference in case you were not aware, when you post your answer, in this case code.  I have done this for you for this post and the change will be visible when my edits have been reviewed.  If you can select all your code and then click the {} at the top of the "Your Answer" area, it will go through and automatically add for spaces to the front of every line which in turns makes your code very readable.

Comment: See edited answer to prevent code from failing should the searched value not be found in Table2 first column

Comment: Not sure you want WsFk_Row to be incremented in any case  (as it is now). Should this not happen then simply include that increment insider the "If Not found is Nothing" clause by expanding it with the "Then" and "End If" keywords